# Export graphics to PDF without whitespace borders

Tags: graphics, pdf-format

I have created a 3d graphics plot, and I would like to export it to a pdf file, tightly cropped (no whitespace around the outside). But if I try

```
Export["myImage.pdf", myImage, ImageSize -> Automatic, 
  ImagePadding -> None];
```

it still includes quite a lot of whitespace around the outside. How can I achieve what I want? I don't want to use ImageCrop because it rasterizes my image (also, it doesn't do a tight crop, it still leaves some whitespace). I am aware of related posts, but I don't know of a method which will perform this function automatically without me manually having to enter the box dimensions I'm trying to crop.

Comment: I wonder if the remaining whitespace is due to frames around text boxes.